# clang warning: -Wambiguous-ellipsis

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-templates

When implementing `is_function`, I trying to enum every case manually with macro:

```
#define ImplIsFun(QUALIFIERS) \
    template<typename R, typename... Args> \
    struct is_function<R(Args...) QUALIFIERS> : public true_ \
    {}; \
    template<typename R, typename... Args> \
    struct is_function<R(Args... COMMA...) QUALIFIERS> : public true_ \
    {};

    // clang-format off
    ImplIsFun()
    ImplIsFun(const)
    ImplIsFun(&)
    ImplIsFun(&&)
    ImplIsFun(volatile)
    ImplIsFun(noexcept)
    ImplIsFun(const volatile)
    ImplIsFun(const &)
    ImplIsFun(const &&)
    ImplIsFun(const noexcept)
    ImplIsFun(volatile &)
    ImplIsFun(volatile &&)
    ImplIsFun(volatile noexcept)
    ImplIsFun(const volatile &)
    ImplIsFun(const & noexcept)
    ImplIsFun(const && noexcept )
    ImplIsFun(const volatile &&)
    ImplIsFun(const volatile noexcept)
    // clang-format on
```

And warning occur:

```
../include/rider/faiz/type_traits.hpp:315:2: warning: '...' in this location creates a C-style
      varargs function [-Wambiguous-ellipsis]
        ImplIsFun(const &&)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wambiguous-ellipsis

> This diagnostic is enabled by default.
>
> Diagnostic text:
>
> warning: ’…’ in this location creates a C-style varargs function, not a function parameter pack

So,  C-style varargs may conflicit with template variadic. Is there any workaround/solution (boost.preprocessor, hana or other code generator library also welcome)?

Comment: You are making a very far reaching conclusion from the warning. It's not warning about conflict. It's there to warn you that you may have written a c-style varargs function **accidentally**.  `Args... COMMA...` is clearly no accident.

Comment: Oops, please forgive my poor English. So, you mean compiler will just treat `...` here as template variadic? In my local testcases, it does compile happily.

Comment: No it's a c style varargs function. Which is fine, beacause those should be handled too.

Comment: _those should be handled too._ I'm still confused that if `...` above is treated as c style varags, then propressor will remove them because I have no `__VA_ARGS__` argument provided. But the testcases and [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/U3zh4F)(link updated) both tell me `...` isn't removed by preprocessor.

Comment: @陳力 - a C-style varargs function, not a variadic macro; look for `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, etc. By example, give a look at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)

Comment: @max66 My bad. I misunderstand what StoryTeller said. Thanks for explaination(I didn't know them before)